# Where's this waterfront with a ferris wheel in Yokohama, in Episode 41 of "Terrace House: Boys & Girls in the City"?

Tags: japan, locate-this

These screenshots are from ["Episode 41 of  "Terrace House: Boys & Girls in the City" released on Mon Mar 28, 2016"](https://www.tvtime.com/en/show/309785/episode/5711309). 
[YouTube has a clip](https://youtu.be/XfR0OSbeMCU) of this scene.

I can't spot it beneath in  [this map created by a fan](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=13T6nXZcJkK49AZAjj-34wfrNr_c&ll=35.11472882438712%2C144.7772890996555&z=5)? [This Reddit user's map](https://redd.it/9n87hf) pinpoints a ferris wheel, but not the scene beneath?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ferris wheel is located in Minatomirai on the waterfront. It shows up in a lot of picutes if you search for Minatomirai on Google images. (My Browser doesn’t have an URL in the URL bar for some reason so I cannot link but trust it should work. I am not linking to images directly for copyright reasons.)

[Here](https://goo.gl/maps/GgyXGVjMQuT2) is a Google Maps link to a spot where the scene may have been shot; if not, a little closer to the wheel but move as intended. I have included the Street view screenshot below.

[image: Google Street View of Minatomirai ferris wheel]

Comment: this URL will help https://www.google.com/maps/@35.4513847,139.6471397,3a,75y,14.04h,74.32t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sAF1QipNPQ_SGiZtbRd8KMNrEYqSek9mEDlwQ7UZc73YV!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipNPQ_SGiZtbRd8KMNrEYqSek9mEDlwQ7UZc73YV%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi0-ya288.93393-ro-0-fo100!7i5376!8i2688